# Up laravel project and get (The requested URL /icons/create was not found on this server.) but route exist and any route works perfectly

Tags: laravel, apache

Running a project in dev server run perfectly but I try to move on a live server, I got "The requested URL /icons/create was not found on this server."

i got that just in 1 route in : .../icon/create
but any route works fine.

[image]

this is my htaccess :
[image]

I try to `composer dump-autoload` in local but don't get any error"

or something problem in my htaccess file?
mod_rewrite already enable in the apache web server.

Very thank you, if someone wants to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

as u r saying u have **"mod_rewrite already enable"**

try this  editing `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Change the `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Comment: i try that, but still nothing sir. or must restar apache ?

Answer (score 0):

Comment Alias in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf`.

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    # Aliases: Add here as many aliases as you need (with no limit). The format is
    # Alias fakename realname
    #
    # Note that if you include a trailing / on fakename then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  So "/icons" isn't aliased in this
    # example, only "/icons/".  If the fakename is slash-terminated, then the
    # realname must also be slash terminated, and if the fakename omits the
    # trailing slash, the realname must also omit it.
    #
    # We include the /icons/ alias for FancyIndexed directory listings.  If
    # you do not use FancyIndexing, you may comment this out.

#   Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"

#   <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/icons">
#       Options FollowSymlinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#   </Directory>

</IfModule>
```

After Comment these lines check apache conf using this command:

```
sudo apache2ctl -t
```

Then reload apache2:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```